# Transfer shares to avoid brokerage fees

Tags: etf, fees, brokerage, transfer

I like Fidelity better than Vanguard in regards to web interface and customer service. Vanguard has better funds for the way I wish to invest. Since I plan to invest in a dollar/cost averaging manner 1-2x/mo, it will be smaller amounts and so buying Vanguard ETFs through Fidelity would really eat into my money (given a moderately diversified portfolio of around 7 ETFs). Given all this, I have looked into transferring shares, and see no fees mentioned to do so. Doing a quick google search has lead me to believe that it will cost nothing - http://www.onlinebrokerrev.com/commissions_and_fees/account-transfer-fees.php

This being the case, is there any downside to using the free transfer of shares, to avoid the brokerage fees?

Comment: How often do you plan to transfer? This sounds like a lot of work to avoid just staying at Vanguard.

Comment: Let's see now. You hold shares in some Vanguard ETFs that you bought on Vanguard's website, possibly through Vanguard's in-house brokerage. You want to transfer the shares and hold them in your account Fidelity's brokerage house. You want to base your decision on the fact that a review of 8 brokerage houses (including Fidelity) makes no mention of any fees that Fidelity might be charging for this. So, did you notice that the review has not been updated for nearly two years, and the author of the review has abandoned the project? Are the fees (or lack of fees) the same now as they were then?